# Google Datastore low-level api query by key property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the low-level google datastore api and I want to query by the key property and another property (let's call it category).

I need to query based on a list of keys for which I'll use the IN operator. I know that the max. number of values you can provide for the IN clause is 30.

I have 2 questions:

1. Does the limit of 30 IN values apply to the key property as well?
2. Do I need to create a composite index on {__key__ + category} or just on {category} for this query?

Thanks,
Keyur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the limit is only on the IN values.
2. No, you won't need an index.

If you can avoid doing IN queries, though, do so - an IN query is internally evaluated as multiple equality queries, one per element in the IN.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Other than IN is there another way for me to filter on a set of keys? The DatastoreService.get(keys) returns me all entities corresponding to the keys but doesn't let me apply another filter on them.

Comment: Retrieve all the keys in your list, then filter manually. It'll still be substantially faster than doing one query per entity!

Comment: What if I have like a million keys and need to find if 100 keys currently with me exist in these million keys?

Comment: @Nischal I don't understand what you're asking. What is the nature of the test you need to perform on these million keys?

Comment: @nick-johnson Sorry about that and I've been over enthusiastic about this question. The first comment here actually answers my query. What I needed to know is if I had to lookup 100 keys (I create key objects using email addresses as the unique thingy), I guess I need to use DatastoreService.get(List of keys)